# jquery $(' tr:even ') is not working for alterantive row colors

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

i have the following jquery code but the whole table is rendering grey bg instead of even as i expected,i check in the chrome  30.0v

```
  $('#tenantsTbl tr:even').css('background-color','grey');
```

Comment: have you checked the td & table background colors?  if the td has a color, it might be overriding the tr.  you might try `#tenantsTbl tr:even td` as your selector just to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#tenantsTbl tr:even td').css('background-color','grey');
```